# SQL Query: Calculating the deltas in a time series

Tags: sql, ms-access

For a development aid project I am helping a small town in Nicaragua improving their water-network-administration.

There are about 150 households and every month a person checks the meter and charges the houshold according to the consumed water (reading from this month minus reading from last month). Today all is done on paper and I would like to digitalize the administration to avoid calculation-errors.

I have an MS Access Table in mind - e.g.:

```
*HousholdID*  *Date*     *Meter*
0             1/1/2013   100
1             1/1/2013   130
0             1/2/2013   120
1             1/2/2013   140
...
```

From this data I would like to create a query that calculates the consumed water (the meter-difference of one household between two months)

```
*HouseholdID*  *Date*     *Consumption*
0              1/2/2013   20
1              1/2/2013   10
...
```

Please, how would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query returns every date with previous date, even if there are missing months:

```
SELECT TabPrev.*, Tab.Meter as PrevMeter, TabPrev.Meter-Tab.Meter as Diff
FROM (
  SELECT
    Tab.HousholdID,
    Tab.Data,
    Max(Tab_1.Data) AS PrevData,
    Tab.Meter
  FROM
    Tab INNER JOIN Tab AS Tab_1 ON Tab.HousholdID = Tab_1.HousholdID
                                 AND Tab.Data > Tab_1.Data
  GROUP BY Tab.HousholdID, Tab.Data, Tab.Meter) As TabPrev
  INNER JOIN Tab
  ON TabPrev.HousholdID = Tab.HousholdID
     AND TabPrev.PrevData=Tab.Data
```

Here's the result:

```
HousholdID  Data        PrevData    Meter  PrevMeter  Diff
----------------------------------------------------------
0           01/02/2013  01/01/2013  120    100        20
1           01/02/2013  01/01/2012  140    130        10
```

The query above will return every delta, for every households, for every month (or for every interval). If you are just interested in the last delta, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  MaxTab.*,
  TabCurr.Meter as CurrMeter,
  TabPrev.Meter as PrevMeter,
  TabCurr.Meter-TabPrev.Meter as Diff
FROM ((
  SELECT
    Tab.HousholdID,
    Max(Tab.Data) AS CurrData,
    Max(Tab_1.Data) AS PrevData
  FROM
    Tab INNER JOIN Tab AS Tab_1
        ON Tab.HousholdID = Tab_1.HousholdID
           AND Tab.Data > Tab_1.Data
  GROUP BY Tab.HousholdID) As MaxTab
  INNER JOIN Tab TabPrev
  ON TabPrev.HousholdID = MaxTab.HousholdID
     AND TabPrev.Data=MaxTab.PrevData)
  INNER JOIN Tab TabCurr
  ON TabCurr.HousholdID = MaxTab.HousholdID
     AND TabCurr.Data=MaxTab.CurrData
```

and (depending on what you are after) you could only filter current month:

```
WHERE
  DateSerial(Year(CurrData), Month(CurrData), 1)=
  DateSerial(Year(DATE()), Month(DATE()), 1)
```

this way if you miss a check for a particular household, it won't show.
Or you might be interested in showing last month present in the table (which can be different than current month):

```
WHERE
  DateSerial(Year(CurrData), Month(CurrData), 1)=
  (SELECT MAX(DateSerial(Year(Data), Month(Data), 1))
  FROM Tab)
```

(here I am taking in consideration the fact that checks might be on different days)

Comment: @Remou why you say it doesn't work? It works for me, I'm using Access 2010

Comment: @Remou i didn't want to use Date as a field name, but you can rename it and use [] if you wish....

Comment: Adding some extra records for 01/12/2012 for households 0 and 1, the above returns more that one result for each household.

Comment: It's because I'm returning all deltas, not just the last/current one, yes maybe it's slightly different than the original request (i am not sure), can be fixed if needed, but I thought it might be more useful this way

Comment: Why? Do you not think there is a danger of overcharging when months that have been paid for are returned by the query?

Comment: @Remou sorting by date should avoid the problem, but also showing just the last month it's not always a perfect solution, something could go wrong anyway, so I really don't know what is more safe. I believe it is more dangerous to relay to the fact that all records of every households are present every months, so I wanted to avoid that. I've updated my answer, maybe it's not necessary to calculate `Max(Tab.Data)`, we could just use current month instead, but that depends on what the OP is after.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is to use a correlated subquery to get the previous date and join back to the original table.  This ensures that you get the previous record, even if there is more or less than a 1 month lag.

So the right query looks like:

```
select t.*, tprev.date, tprev.meter
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 date from t t2 where t2.date < t.date order by date desc
             ) prevDate
      from t
     ) join
     t tprev
     on tprev.date = t.prevdate
```

In an environment such as the one you describe, it is very important not to make assumptions about the frequency of reading the meter.  Although they may be read on average once per month, there will always be exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Testing with the following data:

```
HousholdID  Date        Meter
0           01/12/2012  100
1           01/12/2012  130
0           01/01/2013  120
1           01/01/2013  140
0           01/02/2013  120
1           01/02/2013  140
```

The following query:

```
SELECT a.housholdid, 
   a.date, 
   b.date, 
   a.meter, 
   b.meter, 
   a.meter - b.meter AS Consumption
FROM   (SELECT * 
    FROM   water 
    WHERE  Month([date]) = Month(Date()) 
           AND Year([date])=year(Date())) a 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
              FROM water
              WHERE DateSerial(Year([date]),Month([date]),Day([date]))
               =DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,Day([date])) ) b 
   ON a.housholdid = b.housholdid
```

The above query selects the records for this month `Month([date]) = Month(Date())` and compares them to records for last month `([date]) = Month(Date()) - 1)`

**Please do not use Date as a field name.**

Returns the following result.

```
housholdid  a.date      b.date      a.meter b.meter Consumption
0           01/02/2013  01/01/2013  120     100     20
1           01/02/2013  01/01/2013  140     130     10
```

Comment: +1  "Please do not use Date as a field name." Agreed.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) for a complete list of keywords to avoid.

Comment: The data illustrated was from one year. It is not difficult to add a check for years.

Comment: @mwolfe02 thank you for stressing what said, I have added my own emphasis.

Comment: @HansUp, if you read more carefully, you will see that they are. Both refer to **day([date])**.

Comment: @HansUp The sample data does not show readings for random days, only for the first of the month. Surely you have better things to do?

Comment: Hans, the days are illustrated as the same, why not just leave it at the data that is shown. You can argue away the next time, when the data is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select  t.householdID
       , max(s.theDate) as billingMonth
       , max(s.meter)-max(t.meter) as waterUsed
from    myTbl t join (
    select  householdID, max(theDate) as theDate, max(meter) as meter
    from    myTbl 
    group by householdID ) s 
        on t.householdID = s.householdID and t.theDate <> s.theDate
group by t.householdID
```

This works in SQL not sure about access

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LAG() function in certain SQL dialects. I found this to be much faster and easier to read than joins.

Source: http://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/12/use-this-neat-window-function-trick-to-calculate-time-differences-in-a-time-series/