# Calculating deltas in time series with duplicate & missing values

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series

I have an Oracle table that consist of tuples of logtime/value1, value2..., plus additional columns such as a metering point id. The values are sampled values of different counters that are each monotonically increasing, i.e. a newer value cannot be less than an older value. However, values can remain equal for several samplings, and values can miss sometimes, so the corresponding table entry is NULL while other values of the same logtime are valid. Also, the intervals between logtimes are not constant.

In the following, for simplicity I will regard only the logtime and one counter value.

I have to calculate the deltas from each logtime to the previous one. Using the method described in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717393/sql-query-calculating-the-deltas-in-a-time-series) gives two NULL deltas for each NULL value because two subtractions are invalid. A second solution fails when consecutive values are identical since the difference to the previous value is calculated twice.

Another solution is to construct a derived table/view with those NULL values replaced by the latest older valid value. My approach looks like this:

```
SELECT A.logtime, A.val,
(A.val - (SELECT MAX(C.val) 
          FROM tab C 
          WHERE logtime = 
             (SELECT MAX(B.logtime) 
              FROM tab B 
              WHERE B.logtime < A.logtime AND B.val IS NOT NULL))) AS delta
FROM tab A;
```

I suspect that this will result in a quite inefficient query, especially when doing this for all N counters in the table which will result in (1 + 2*N) SELECTs. It also does not take advantage from the fact that the counter is monotonically increasing.

Are there any alternative approaches? I'd think others have similar problems, too.

An obvious solution would of course be filling in those NULL values constructing a new table or modifying the existing table, but unfortunately that is not possible in this case. Avoiding/eliminating them on entry isn't possible either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you order them by time and order by counter then you could user http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php#lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
   logtime, 
   val, 
   last_value(val ignore nulls) over (order by logtime) 
      as not_null_val,
   last_value(val ignore nulls) over (order by logtime) - 
      last_value(val ignore nulls) over (order by logtime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
      as delta  
from your_tab order by logtime;
```

Comment: I found a way to avoid the nested SELECT statements using Oracle SQL's build-in LAG function:

    SELECT logtime, val,
           NVL(val-LAG(val IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY logtime), 0) AS delta
    FROM tab;

seems to work as I intended.

Comment: @stefan - then post your solution here.  (You are allowed to answer your own question).

Comment: @Stefan - Your own solution is better than mine.

Comment: @Egor: I'm still trying to understand the fine differences between LAST_VALUE and LAG as they are used in this context… :-)

Comment: @APC: just have a look into my answer to Egor. But I'll post it as a separate answer, too. Btw, I cannot answer my own questions unless they are older than 7 hours. That is a restriction by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to avoid the nested SELECT statements using Oracle SQL's build-in LAG function:

```
SELECT logtime, val,
       NVL(val-LAG(val IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY logtime), 0) AS delta
FROM tab;
```

seems to work as I intended.

*(Repeated here as a separate answer)*